# PhalconPHP. Render volt template to variable

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I'd like to generate html code from volt template to variable. How to do this?

```
$this->view->pick('foo/bar');
$this->view->setVar('foo', $bar);
$html = $this->view->???
```

Comment: Your question is not clear Do you want to pass variable data controller to view page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to load the content of your views into a variable.

One way is to return the output of your view as a string by calling `render` on your `$view`.
This will only load the specific view and not the template.

```
$this->view->setVar('foo', $bar);
$html = $this->view->getRender('controller', 'action');
```

---

An other option to load your view (with a template):

```
$this->view->start();
$this->view->setVar('foo', 'test');
$this->view->setTemplateAfter('default'); // template name
$this->view->render('controller', 'action');
$this->view->finish();

$html = $this->view->getContent();
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#id1) you can also find other ways to achieve this.